# Media Streaming server in C#.NET

Tags: c#-4.0, video-streaming, .net-4.5, live-streaming

I'm trying to create a media streaming server which will stream images captured from camera to connected javascript/html clients.

Currently, I have developed a windows service which captures images and sends it to multiple clients through continuously polling, however, it lags in performance. For example, it congests the network with too much traffic, and creates delay in streams.
[image]

The service is running on Hyper V VM with 6 cores and 8 Gb memory.

Where can I find the lag? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a queue or use something like SignalR. Looks for something like reduce to send traffic in network like ziping or cache

Look for Hangfire.io its good too

Comment: On the server side it has multiple queues one for each image captured by camera, and another for sending data from server to client. So not sure if it'll help. I'm looking for multi-casting options but have no clue about it for now.